# Capturing packets without connecting to the WLAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark

How can wireless sniffers capture packets from a WLAN without being connected to that specific WLAN (without having access credentials of that WLAN by any means). 
How to get the interface of that WLAN to be appeared on the wireshark interface list?

Answer (score 3):

Activate the **monitor mode** – if your Wi-Fi device supports it:

- https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Turning_on_monitor_mode
- For Linux, `iw wlan0 interface add mon0 type monitor; ip link set mon0 up` works.